# authentication for a REST Api designed for 1 consumer and heavy use

Tags: api, rest, authentication

The company I work for is outsourcing their ecommerce site, but maintaining order management in their legacy system. (Why? Politics). We are building an API so the new ecommerce site can pass order records etc to the legacy system. There will be a ton of calls all from this one system, generally in real time. What would be the best authentication method given this situation? Efficiency is key here. I'm not sure if knowing the IP of my only consumer gets me much, ie, would some sort of IP authentication be trustworthy, or more efficient than a simple Basic Authentication? I'm guessing I should avoid oauth or rolling my own hmac solution given the extra overhead.

Comment: Sorry if I go beyond your question; but why exposing a WEB Api?
Are there any plan for other clients (mobile?) to consume the api -other than the new e-comm site?

If both systems are in the same network, I would rather use a service bus or even a simpler publisher/subscriber mechanism to tackle the data flow from the new app to the old app.
But I don't know the reasons behind your decision, I'm just trying to make sure you are using the right tool for the job.

Comment: Fair enough. We're not on the same network, but seems worth discussing. Would a VPN be that much more efficient? (FWIW, to your point, they do want to keep the flexibility of exposing the API to other clients in the future, but if the arguments in favor of some other option are strong enough...)

Comment: I have seen a lot of time and effort put in projects that are based in the just-in-case principle (we want to be flexible, and support this and that just in case in the future... etc) and those features never get to be used. But again, I'm just speculating here... you guys have for sure a better understanding of what your case is.
Yes, if a VPN is an option and not a big hassle for your IT guys, I would just create my biz services around the old system, and use a Service Bus, or even implement a simpler Pub/Subs mechanism maybe using MSMQ or similar.

Comment: Then have the new system dropping messages with the orders and data in general you need to move to your back end.
You can ALWAYS wrap this business services and expose them in a restful manner -when the time comes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your audience. If this is for internal consumption only, checking the ip or adding basic auth through https should be more than enough.

If you are planning on exposing your business to other clients, then you might want to implement a more complex auth mechanism. I like what [Amazon uses](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html) but you guys can tweak this to meet your own needs.